# EasyApache 4 - Handler "application/x-httpd-ea-php70" not found

Tags: apache-http-server, whm

I've installed EasyApache 4 in WHM and things look good, but when I provision w/ the cPanel Default profile, all my PHP files end up 500 errors and `Caused by KeyNotFoundException in Configuration.cpp:262: Handler "application/x-httpd-ea-php70" not found` is what shows up in the Apache error logs.

If I swap to a lower PHP or back to the "Basic" EA4 configuration, I continue to get the same error for other versions of PHP - `Caused by KeyNotFoundException in Configuration.cpp:262: Handler "application/x-httpd-ea-php56" not found`

**Anyone know why:**
A. The EA4 profile wouldn't install and configure the handler correctly?
B. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Less than exciting - I reprovisioned to the EasyApache 4 "Basic" package, at which point things worked, and then back to the package I had been trying to use, and things started working.